# Content type with buttons such as "I'm going here" and "I have been here"

Tags: 7, users, nodes, location

Is there a way to have a content type for a location (I've already set up the map part) so users can click a link and say whether they've been there or not and it will show on their profile as 'places visited' and 'places planning on going'.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module for this.  We have used this module for similar purposes with good results.

You should be able to set up “I'm going here” and “I have been here” as different "flags", and then enable these flags on the content types you need.  This particular module integrates nicely with Views, Actions, and other Drupal mechanisms.